# Binary Search error when doesn't find a number

Tags: ruby, sorting, mergesort

I've created a binary search, while looking at the online wiki. I have a class of [Athletes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42151156/adding-to-ruby-objects/42151235?noredirect=1#comment71469207_42151235) that each have a name and number. I'm inputting a file text or csv, doesn't matter - with each of the athletes name's and numbers. My program sorts them first, and then I am trying to add the functionality of searching for a number based off of user input, and displaying who wears that numbered jersey. So my initial post was trying to binary search for people with the same number. As in, if I had Michael Jordan and Lebron James on my list, they both wear 23 - so when my search goes through it would only output 1 (whichever it comes to first). I was looking for how to make my search (below) accept/find multiple occurrences of a number. However, upon further testing, I found that if I input a number not actually in my list it would give me the error: `search: stack level too deep` which I don't know what that means. I think my search doesn't handle properly if there's no instance of the number, or if the array is 0.
So I was looking for some help to see how I can fix this to work if the number input by a user isn't in the list. So if someone inputs "1000" -- no one has worn that jersey number and should return false. Or something of that sort, break, whatever.

```
def search(array, num, start = 0, last = nil)
  if last == nil
    last = array.count - 1
  end

  mid = (start + last) / 2

  if num < array[mid].number
    return search(array, num, start, mid - 1)
  elsif num > array[mid].number
    return search(array, num, mid + 1, last)
  else
    return mid
  end
end
```

I've now also gotten `==: stack level too deep` on the line where `if last == nil`

Comment: It looks like you've been editing this question but right now it makes little sense.  You should tell us what you are trying to do and provide an [mcve] and explain what the problem is with your current attempt, and ask a clear question.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the ruby way of doing things.  When you have a collection, and you would like to only select some of them based on a certain condition, The ruby approach would be to use [Enumerable#select](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html)

You would ideally have some array of athletes like so

```
athletes = [Athlete.new, Athlete.new]
athletes_with_number_23 = athletes.select { |athlete| athlete.number == 23 } #if you want all
first_athlete_wearing_23 = athletes.detect { |athlete| athlete.number == 23 } #if you want only the first one
```

Disclaimer: this is pseudo code.

Comment: I'm aware, but trying to implement other things that Ruby may already have, like sorting. I found that my search doesn't even work properly if I put in a number that's not on the list. Is there any way you can help me with that first?

Answer (score 0):

I changed my search function:

```
def search(array, key)
  lo = 0
  hi = array.length-1

  while(lo <= hi)
    mid = lo + ((hi-lo)/2)

    if array[mid].number == key
      return mid
    elsif array[mid].number < key
      lo = mid + 1
    else
      hi = mid - 1
    end
  end

  puts "Value not found in array"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If I got u right you wanna get ALL athletes with a specific number in a sorted list.

First. Your code is a way too procedural, "This is not the ruby way of doing things.". But I guess it doesn't matter for you.

So, I suggest you find an index of one of the athletes and just walk array left and right from it to collect same-number mans.

Here my procedural version. It uses your function.

```
def athletes_with_number(athletes, number)
  result = []
  found_index = search(athletes, number)
  return result unless found_index

  # walk left
  i = found_index
  while i >= 0 && athletes[i].number == number
    result << athletes[i]
    i -= 1
  end

  # walk right
  i = found_index + 1 # athletes[found_index] already added
  while i < athletes.size && athletes[i].number == number
    result << athletes[i]
    i += 1
  end
  result
end

def search(array, key)
  lo = 0
  hi = array.length-1

  while(lo <= hi)
    mid = lo + ((hi-lo)/2)

    if array[mid].number == key
      return mid
    elsif array[mid].number < key
      lo = mid + 1
    else
      hi = mid - 1
    end
  end

  nil
end
```